# Missing files in enqueue actions causes WordPress to reload

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Tell me if I'm nuts, but here goes nothing...

I was debugging some code tonight and put an error_log( 'success' ) into the main file of my plugin. I was kinda baffled as to why it printed that to my console three times every time I loaded up my site.

After a bit of research I found out that if you try to enqueue a script in a plugin that can't be found, for some reason WP will just reload the entire site each time. Also, apparently if you try to enqueue a script with a dependency that doesn't exist, the same will happen.

Can someone gut-check me on this?

I put that same error_log statement into my functions.php file and it did the same thing.

Is it really reloading each file when it can't find an enqueued script or a dependency, or am I so completely off base about this?

Comment: This isn't normal. Where exactly did you add the error_log function? In a function?

Comment: And how do you enqueue these files?

Comment: I added the error_log function into functions.php and into the main file of a plugin (not at the same time). It just prints a message to my terminal. The files are enqueued in the standard WordPress way.